# how the new leader know actual lastApplied because lastApplied is volatile?

Tags: consensus, raft

my question is that if the leader crash, but is elected as leader again. how does it know its actual lastApplied? will it apply log entries repeatedly?

I want to know how it work

Answer (score 0):

lastApplied is tracked on each node individually, both leader and followers. All node must have a persistent storage, where the value (and other data) resides.

So if a node restarts after crash, it would read the lastApplied from that storage.

If the storage is completely lost, it's the same case if a brand new node needs to be added to the pool.

Quick edit: lastApplied index works the same way for both leader and followers. There is nothing special about it based on the node role.